# Android - Inteligent loader for item thumbs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

In a GridView I should display several images. All the images are downloaded from the internet.
All this functionality is already done and works like a charm, but at some point you realize this is not the best implementation.

Consider the GridView has several hundreds of images. In this case I would like to download only those images, that are visible to the user, or fits in the visible area of the screen.
If I scroll down the gallery, I want to cancel (if any) the previous started downloads, and start downloading the images that are visible to the user.

Could you suggest me some hints how I would go implementing this?

Or suggest some libraries. Right now I'm looking at Ignition, but it seems it loads all the gallery at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're describing lazy loading. There's a [question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview) with great answers. In a simple case I used Fedor's library, which works great. A more complex solution is offered by NOSTRA.

From what I've seen, [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) does exactly what you would want it to do. It can be found [here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) on github.